# Tabulator 5.1 setHeaderFilterValue displaying value instead of label with "select" type header filter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm working with Tabulator 5.1 and I've created a table with a "status" column. The "status" value is an integer.

I have a "select" header filter setup for that column. I have defined a setup of values array the define a "label" to be displayed for each possible value.

When I click on the header filter, it presents a list of the status labels as it should. I can set the value by selecting one of the "labels".

However, if I try setting the header filter in code using setHeaderFilterValue (grid.setHeaderFilterValue('status', 2), the header filter displays the value ("2") instead of displaying the associated label ("Enabled").

I don't see it documented that it should work this way, but it doesn't seem to make sense that this is intended.

Here is some example code (same code found in the jsfiddle):

```
var column_defs = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Status',
    field: 'status',
    headerFilter: 'select',
    headerFilterFunc: '=' ,
    headerFilterParams: {
        values: [
        {value: '', label: ''},
        {value: 1, label: 'Unknonw'},
        {value: 2, label: 'Enabled'},
        {value: 3, label: 'Paused'}
      ]
    },
    formatter: 'lookup',
    formatterParams: {
        0: '',
        1: 'Unknown',
        2: 'Enabled',
        3: 'Paused',
    }
  }
];

var data = [
    {name: 'Campaign A', status: 1},
    {name: 'Campaign B', status: 2},
    {name: 'Campaign C', status: 2},
    {name: 'Campaign D', status: 3},
    {name: 'Campaign E', status: 3},
    {name: 'Campaign F', status: 3},
];

var grid = new Tabulator('#grid-content', {
    data: data,
    columns: column_defs,
});

grid.on('tableBuilt', function() {
    grid.setHeaderFilterValue('status', 2);
})
```

Working Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/L3kyrtcz/

To Reproduce:

1. Go to https://jsfiddle.net/L3kyrtcz/
2. Click Run
3. Look at the header filter for the status column
4. See the number "2" displayed instead of "Enabled"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the values from numbers to strings, There is likely a strict type comparison issue here

Comment: just tried and it made no difference